# MYSQL - Use Group By with Order By with Joins

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

Currently, I am having a query as below to get the counts based on the groups as below, But I having an issue with doing order by with group by when we are using the left join.

I have tried below but it's not doing the Order By based on the Status

**SQL Fiddle** : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a4594/1/0

`SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        t.Status, COUNT(*) AS 'Count'
    FROM
        Processess P
    LEFT JOIN Tasks T ON P.TaskId = T.TaskId
    GROUP BY t.Status) x
ORDER BY x.Status ASC;`

It gives me the result as

```
Status  | Count
----------
OPEN | 10
----------
DONE | 20
----------
```

But I wanted as

```
Status  | Count
----------
DONE| 20
----------
OPEN| 10
----------
```

Comment: Your query *should* work. Can you share some sample data that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @Nick I have updated the SQL Fiddle Now, I have guessed that it's happening because of enum

Answer (score 0):

Try below -

```
SELECT t.Status, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM
        Processess P
    LEFT JOIN Tasks T ON P.TaskId = T.TaskId
    GROUP BY t.Status order by t.Status
```

Comment: OP **specifically** said they want to order by status. What if the counts were the other way around?

Comment: Yeah I want by Status that is the problem I am facing now

Comment: I have tried the edited answer as well still it doesn't show based on the order of Status

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the reason because Order By was not working due to the filed type ENUM

Hence finally below Query worked for me

`SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        t.Status, COUNT(*) AS 'Count'
    FROM
        Processess P
    LEFT JOIN Tasks T ON P.TaskId = T.TaskId
    GROUP BY t.Status) x
ORDER BY CAST(x.Status AS CHAR) ASC;`

Comment: Yeah - enums always sort in the order the values are defined. Had you defined the enum as `('DONE', 'OPEN')` it would have sorted the way you wanted. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87d757/1 Sorry I wasn't around to take a look, been night here. Anyway, you should accept your own answer when the timer runs out.